# Resume and pause python script (telethon)

Tags: python, resume, telethon, pause

**I apologize from the start for my English...**

Hello, I'm a little new, rather what I did here is my best and greatest work. Of course I did not do it on my own, I was inspired by many other works, Forums, Forums and forums. In the program below, if it can be called a program. I need to do, say, a little "pause" and "continue" system if I can. I would do this myself, but I have no idea how, I spent half a day, trying various methods. I think it was working, or not, I don't know... For example, I put that when the program stops to print me "paused" and when it starts back to write "continuing"... But that's all that was going on after we added this system... Because the program wasn't working... And I don't know where I'm wrong... If anyone can help me, I'd be grateful...
And if you can, tell me where to add that piece of program. In the middle, at the beginning or at the end.
As far as you can see, there are quite a few imported things... And I'm not even sure if I need most of them... The only library imported by me is Regex "re":).

```
import re
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
from telethon.tl.types import Channel
from telethon.tl.types import ChatForbidden
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChat
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendMessageRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel


api_id = *******
api_hash = '***************************'

client = TelegramClient('Test', api_id, api_hash).start()

#entity_v2 = client.get_entity('searaseara') #Success

me = client.get_me()   
#print(me.stringify())


@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r'\d*\s*\bне выкуплено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bотправлено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bоплачено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bнекорректный\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bотменено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bвыкуплено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bотказ\b.*\b1CALL\b|Пропущеный звонок с номера\b'))
async def handler(event):
    await event.respond(message="+")

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use python simple if

```
s = off
if s == "on":
    #Do_sth
```

and you can control this(turning on or off) with getting message from your client(telegram)

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern="turn"))
async def handler(event):
    txt = event.raw_text
    global s
    if txt == "turnon":
        s = "on"
    if txt == "turnoff":
        s = "off"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
I may not have expressed myself correctly, I apologize.
But I need to pause and continue the program at any time I need, not just when I get a message, if I express myself correctly.

Comment: You can still change the `s` variable at any time you need. Just stop reacting whenever the variable is not `on` (or better, use a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found a little Solution, How can I pause the program and get it to continue, only it's a little problem.
For example, this program responds with "+" to messages containing the words in the pattern... But if in the meantime, the program is paused, and more messages come in, which the program usually should have responded to, for example 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on, when I take it out of the pause, it sends pluses for each message... For example, the program responds to the message "123" with "+". A small example below how the program usually works:

1. Sender: 123
2. Me:+
3. Sender: 123
4. Me:+
5. Sender: 123
6. Me:+
7. Sender: 123
8. Me:+
9. Sender: 123
10. Me:+

Another example when the program is on pause then I remove it from pause after receiving a few messages:

1. Sender: 123
2. Sender: 123
3. Sender: 123
4. Sender: 123
5. Sender: 123
6. Sender: 123
7. Sender: 123
8. Me:+
9. Me:+
10. Me:+
11. Me:+
12. Me:+
13. Me:+
14. Me:+

```
import re
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync, events
from telethon.tl.types import Channel
from telethon.tl.types import ChatForbidden
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerChat
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import SendMessageRequest
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel


api_id = 5531856
api_hash = '94a4bf4ea16117ddf5dc5ffa61d54dbf'


###################################################
#I added this section
def debug_signal_handler(signal, frame):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, debug_signal_handler)
###################################################








client = TelegramClient('Test', api_id, api_hash).start()

#entity_v2 = client.get_entity('searaseara') #Success

me = client.get_me()   
print(me.stringify())



@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, pattern=r'\d*\s*\bне выкуплено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bотправлено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bоплачено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bнекорректный\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bотменено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bвыкуплено\b.*\b1CALL\b|\d*\s*\bотказ\b.*\b1CALL\b|Пропущеный звонок с номера\b'))
async def handler(event):
    await event.respond(message="+")


client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: this should be an edit to your question insnead IMHO